# Generate .exe file from .py code using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, pyinstaller

I try to generate an exe file from .py code, but something wrong with numpy module import, error details show below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py", line 24, in 
>         File "c:\users\andy.xu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 621, in exec_module
>           exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>         File "site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in 
>         File "c:\users\andy.xu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 621, in exec_module
>           exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>         File "site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in 
>       ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "PE_HELPER.py", line 7, in 
>         File "c:\users\andy.xu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 621, in exec_module
>           exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>         File "site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line 142, in 
>         File "c:\users\andy.xu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 621, in exec_module
>           exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>         File "site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py", line 54, in 
>      ImportError:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
>      - Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
>      - If you have already done that, then:
>         1. Check that you expected to use Python3.8 from "C:\Users\andy.xu\dist\PE_HELPER.exe",
>            and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
>            interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.2" you're trying to use.
>         2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
>            https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
>            - how you installed Python
>            - how you installed numpy
>            - your operating system
>            - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
>            - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log
>
> - If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
>       (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
>
>   Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
>     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
>
>   Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.
>
>   [51560] Failed to execute script PE_HELPER

it seems import numpy error, and the modules imported in my code all shows below:

```
import pymysql
import sys, os, time

time1 = time.time()
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID("myappid")
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.use('QT5Agg')
from functools import wraps
import seaborn as sns
import PyQt5

dirname = os.path.dirname(PyQt5.__file__)
plugin_path = os.path.join(dirname, 'plugins', 'platforms')
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = plugin_path
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QTableView, QAbstractItemView, \
    QWidget, QDialog, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QApplication, QLineEdit, QTextBrowser, QFileDialog, QTreeWidget, \
    QTreeWidgetItem, \
    QRadioButton, QCheckBox, QAction, QMenu, QShortcut, QComboBox, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QColor, QKeySequence, QBrush, QRegExpValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal, QAbstractTableModel, QMutex, QRegExp
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

import itertools
import qdarkstyle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.types import NVARCHAR, Float, Integer
import pythoncom
from win32com.client import DispatchEx
import re
```

I will great appreciate, thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you use python 3.8 in your PC now?

Comment: yes, win10 platform and python3.8, numpy 1.18.2

Comment: is there anything problem with python 3.8? should i try python 3.7 or other version?

Comment: @xufang pyinstaller always has problems with recent versions of python, I recommend using a virtualenv with python3.6

Comment: yes, i have tried back to python 3.7.7, and can work now, thanks